# Error while performing pip install open_excel

Tags: python, python-2.7

**pip install open_excel**

---

```
Collecting open_excel   Using cached open_excel-0.101a0.tar.gz (6.5 kB) Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from open_excel) (2.6.4) Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from openpyxl->open_excel) (1.4.1) Requirement already satisfied: et_xmlfile in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from openpyxl->open_excel) (1.0.1) Building wheels for collected packages: open-excel   Building wheel for open-excel (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-nyWtv9
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/   Complete output (14 lines):   /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:476: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.101a' to '0.101a0'
    normalized_version,   running bdist_wheel   running build   running build_py   creating build   creating build/lib   creating build/lib/open_excel   copying open_excel/__init__.py -> build/lib/open_excel   copying open_excel/open_excel.py -> build/lib/open_excel   copying open_excel/search_excel.py -> build/lib/open_excel   running build_scripts   creating build/scripts-2.7   error: open_excel: Is a directory  
----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for open-excel   Running setup.py clean for open-excel Failed to build open-excel Installing collected packages: open-excel
    Running setup.py install for open-excel ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-nTesj4/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python2.7/open-excel
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/
    Complete output (14 lines):
    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:476: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.101a' to '0.101a0'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/open_excel
    copying open_excel/__init__.py -> build/lib/open_excel
    copying open_excel/open_excel.py -> build/lib/open_excel
    copying open_excel/search_excel.py -> build/lib/open_excel
    running build_scripts
    creating build/scripts-2.7
    error: open_excel: Is a directory
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UB5LPQ/open-excel/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-nTesj4/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/include/python2.7/open-excel Check the logs for full command output.
```

---

Answer (score 0):

That install seems to be buggy.  It uses openpyxl, so you'll want to update yours from (2.6.4) to (3.0.5)

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable
Pick whichever one works for your OS:

```
pip install -U openpyxl
pip3 install -U openpyxl

python -m pip install -U openpyxl
python3 -m pip install -U openpyxl

py -m pip install -U openpyxl
py -3 -m pip install -U openpyxl
```

Save his scripts into the dir you are using, or a directory in your PATH, then import them as usual.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mohameosam/open_excel/master/open_excel.py

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mohameosam/open_excel/master/search_excel.py

You can also submit a bug-report on GitHub, to let him know
https://github.com/mohameosam/open_excel/issues

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick reply. As I want to use it as part of my Ansible code, need this pacakge as part of Python 2.x. I was able to install as part of Python 3.x, but couldnt use it in ansible as it doesn't recognize Python3.x